# Find Average of timestamp

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

I have a data with 3 cols and I am calculating the pair occurrence of `Col[0]` and `Col[1]` and sum the value in `Col[2]` corresponding to pairs`Col[0]` and `Col[1]`. I can very well find these things but I am also trying to calculate the average of value in `Col[3]` corresponding to `Col[0]` and `Col[1]`. But When I am calculating the average I get average of all the value and same value is shown for ever value. Any suggestion what should I change?

Input file:

```
3545 3140 51.0
4602 183 2280.0
3545 3140 16.0
4945 3545 333.0
4945 3545 274.0
4391 2814 16.0
4945 3545 386.0
5045 4921 63078.0
5045 3545 896.0
4921 3545 896.0
5045 1683 1108.0
4921 1683 1108.0
5454 4391 4161.0
5454 5070 2755.0
5070 4391 2935.0
```

Code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
paircount = defaultdict(int)
pairtime = defaultdict(float)
pairper = defaultdict(float)
timeavg = defaultdict(float)


#get number of pair occurrences and total time
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as o:
    for numline, line in enumerate((line.split() for line in f), start=1):
        pair = line[0], line[1]
        paircount[pair] += 1
        pairtime[pair] += float(line[2])
    timeavg = pairtime[pair]/numline
    #pairper = dict((pair, c * 100.0 / numline) for (pair, c) in paircount.iteritems())
    for pair, freq in paircount.iteritems():
        #print pair[0], pair[1], c, pairper[pair], pairtime[pair]
        o.write("%s %s %s %s %s \n" % (pair[0], pair[1], freq, pairtime[pair], timeavg))
print 'done'
```

Output

```
col[0] col[1] freq[2] sum[3] avg[4]
785 607 3 7736.0 0.019245523048 
3489 2728 6 63616.0 0.019245523048 
1346 1295 1 422.0 0.019245523048 
4608 1136 2 2198.0 0.019245523048 
3893 2759 1 494.0 0.019245523048 
3530 2282 26 42882.0 0.019245523048 
3350 2542 2 10404.0 0.019245523048 
2655 1411 10 10842.0 0.019245523048 
4212 1613 13 53487.0 0.019245523048 
4503 656 7 4753.0 0.019245523048 
2105 674 1 2584.0 0.019245523048 
5139 1086 1 1488.0 0.019245523048 
3690 2034 6 3319.0 0.019245523048 
3867 1982 1 1134.0 0.019245523048 
4253 282 29 588893.0 0.019245523048
```

Comment: In the o.write(...) line, replace "timeavg" with "pairtime[pair]/paircount[pair]" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to compute the average for each pair, so you must put the `timeavg` computation into the second loop :

```
from collections import defaultdict
paircount = defaultdict(int)
pairtime = defaultdict(float)
pairper = defaultdict(float)
timeavg = defaultdict(float)


#get number of pair occurrences and total time
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as o:
    for numline, line in enumerate((line.split() for line in f), start=1):
        pair = line[0], line[1]
        paircount[pair] += 1
        pairtime[pair] += float(line[2])

    for pair, freq in paircount.iteritems():
        timeavg = pairtime[pair] / freq
        o.write("%s %s %s %s %s \n" % (pair[0], pair[1], freq, pairtime[pair], timeavg))

print 'done'
```

Now the output is :

```
4945 3545 3 993.0 331.0 
4602 183 1 2280.0 2280.0 
4391 2814 1 16.0 16.0 
5045 3545 1 896.0 896.0 
4921 1683 1 1108.0 1108.0 
5454 5070 1 2755.0 2755.0 
3545 3140 2 67.0 33.5 
4921 3545 1 896.0 896.0 
5045 4921 1 63078.0 63078.0 
5070 4391 1 2935.0 2935.0 
5454 4391 1 4161.0 4161.0 
5045 1683 1 1108.0 1108.0
```